# So what's wrong with my iGoogle page?

Tags: google, igoogle

Look at how messed up it is: http://i52.tinypic.com/2wdva54.jpg

This only happens on this PC (regardless of what browser I'm using - it looks like that in all browsers I use). But it works normally fine on my laptop. What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Something on your PC is blocking Google's Javascript.

Look for errors in Firebug.

Comment: Right. Check this out: http://i52.tinypic.com/156zvba.jpg

Can this be fixed?

Comment: What's in the Firebug Net Panel?  http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: There you go: http://i52.tinypic.com/30ljqex.jpg